# Ensure 2 Columns in different tables are identical row by row MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Im looking to compare two different tables row by row to ensure that both the file name and the count associated with the filename match. If either does not match I want to output the two rows that are not matching.

I am Using MySQL as my database for the operation

For example

```
Expected                      Actual
FileName    Count             FileName    Count
name1.txt    4                name1.txt    4
name2.txt    7                name2.txt    7
name3.txt    4                name4.txt    4  (invalid filename)
name5.txt    4                name5.txt    5  (invalid count)

Output:
The fOllowing rows did not match:
Expected:                     Actual:
name3.txt    4                name4.txt    4 (because of filename)
name5.txt    4                name5.txt    5 (because counts are diff)
```

The purposes of this is for a validation script. There are two tables, one for the expected results, and one for the actual results. The sql is to compare the rows in each table to make  sure that they are identical. There are 4 columns in each table. For the tables to be considered "identical" the filename and the count associated to that filename must be found in both tables. If that doesn't happen I would like to output the rows that were not able to find a match.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Join the two tables you're comparing (on filename and count) and use a "union minus" to get the excluded rows.

Comment: ````USE database;
SELECT  filename, count 
FROM table1 t1 
where t1.filename or t1.count not in (  
    select  filename, count
    from table2 t2
)````

Comment: Also tried
````USE database;
SELECT t1.Filename, t1.count 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE (t1.Filename != t2.Filename or t1.count != t2.count)````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `NOT EXISTS` :

Table1 :

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.filename = t1.filename AND t1.count = t2.count);
```

Table2 :

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t2.filename = t1.filename AND t1.count = t2.count);
```

If you want to collate them as one result set then use `union all` :

```
SELECT t1.filename, t1.count, 'table1' as table_name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.filename = t1.filename AND t1.count = t2.count)
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.filename, t2.count, 'table2'
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t2.filename = t1.filename AND t1.count = t2.count);
```

Comment: It seems to be catching significantly more items on table1 then on table2. In theroy each row caught in table1 should have a table2 partner

Comment: @StevenTuer. . . Edit the question add some more data & explain your goal.

Comment: I added some more details

Comment: @StevenTuer. . .  That is what the query does. I have missed `count` in `ON` clause.